# ios jailbreak entitlements sign convert app to ipa

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I signed a app with entitlements via ldid. Its actually a binary within myApp.app. How do I convert that myApp.app to myApp.ipa which can be installed via iExplorer or some other way?

I cannot use xcode to install because of the entitlement based signature..

Comment: Have you [tried this basic method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1494310/119114)?  Also, do you need to install as an .ipa file?  Can you just `scp` the .app directory onto the phone?  Is this app just for installing on your phone, or are you looking to distribute it to a set of users (and if you're looking to distribute it, we might need some more information describing your user base, and how you want to get the app to them).

Comment: @Nate - Thanks. At this point, I just want to install on my phone.. But I would like to see App icon on SpringBoard.. Let me get it on to /usr/Applications/Payload.ipa